# Why am I receiving Apple Mach-O linker (ld) error when I use ffmpeg in iOS Xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ffmpeg

I am getting all these errors I have no idea why I hope you can help me guys.

[image: Errors description]

I have included "avformat.h" in bridging header
I have included all frameworks/libraries needed too

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all required includes and they are included inside extern, you may be seeing name mangling going on. Read this  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Including%20FFmpeg%20headers%20in%20a%20C%2B%2B%20application

This is one possibility if you have already made sure that libraries are in path and included.